# Deleting elements of an array based on block with loop

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby

I have an array that I want to remove certain elements from based on a set of rules. I've written the code below:

```
puts "before: #{people.inspect()}"
puts people.size
people.delete_if do |person|
  rules.each do |rule|
    if rule.check_source(self) && !rule.check_rule(person)
      puts "deleted person #{person.id}" 
      true 
      puts "sanity check"
    end
  end
  false
end
puts "after: #{people.inspect()}"
```

But that code does not work. The array printed before is the same as the array printed after, and "sanity check" is printed, even though I think it shouldn't. I suspect the issue might be because of the loop inside the delete_if block, but I don't know how to fix that.

Here's the console output after an array with 2 people with IDs 2 and 3, where 2 should be deleted and 3 kept:

```
before: [#<Person id: 2>, #<Person id: 3>]
2
deleted person 2
sanity check
after: [#<Person id: 2>, #<Person id: 3>]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that the block you're handing to `delete_if` always evaluates to `false`. Your code structure is like this:

```
people.delete_if do |person|
  # Stuff that `delete_if` doesn't care about ...
  false
end
```

The value of the `each` block doesn't matter since `each` doesn't care what it returns and `delete_if` would never see that anyway. The blocks for `delete_if` and `each` are independent.

You could replace the whole `delete_if` block with a simpler [`any?`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Enumerable.html#method-i-any-3F) call:

```
people.delete_if do |person|
  rules.any? { |rule| rule.check_source(self) && !rule.check_rule(person) }
end
```

and get the result you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

It's returning all the element because you put false at the end of block, delete_if function deletes a particular element If blocks evaluates the condition to be true, for an example, consider the given below code

```
a=[1,2,4,5,6,7]

a.delete_if do |x|
  x>5
end

puts a.inspect
```

output

```
[1, 2, 4, 5]
```

block evaluates condition to be true for 6 and 7 so those elements are deleted from the array. In your case since you are returning false at the end of the block, all the elements remains same. For an example consider the below code

```
a=[1,2,4,5,6,7]

a.delete_if do |x|
  x>5
  false
end

puts a.inspect
```

Output

```
[1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 7]
```

If I return true at the end, then all the elements will be deleted, for an example,

```
a=[1,2,4,5,6,7]

a.delete_if do |x|
  x>5
  true
end

puts a.inspect
```

Output

```
[]
```

That's the reason all your elements remain the same after your execution, Please make sure you are passing the condition in the block of delete_if function.

And also If you pass each iterator inside the block of delete_if, it will return the same array but delete_if function require true  to perform the delete operation So make sure you are giving the condition inside the block.